# На странице настроек не переведена строка про Developer Story

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[В Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/146638068?q=translated%3Ano%20text%3A'If%20you%20have%20a%20Developer%20Story%20on%20Stack%20Overflow').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перевели.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]