# Предложение: удалять устаревшие вопросы на Мете

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, мета, удаление-вопросов

Например: вопросы про перевод/вёрстку, которую починили.

Цель: избавиться от никому ненужного мусора, тем самым повысив качество существующей информации на сайте.

Answer (score 6):

1. Это не мусор.
2. На вопросах по переводам по результатам обычно ставится метка [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be). К примеру, [На странице настроек не переведена строка про Developer Story](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7717/15479). Так что, всегда можно отфильтровать.
3. Старые вопросы в списке вопросов постепенно уходят на последние страницы.
4. Если был пофикшен баг/перевод, а потом снова проявился/пропал, то можно отследить историю проблемы.
5. У нас удаляются только вопросы, нарушающие правила.

Так что, не вижу смысла удалять.

Comment: @edem некоторые да. А некоторые лично мне не нужны, но они ничего не нарушают и не мешают.